# slf4j + lombok + additional logger

Tags: java, slf4j, lombok

I would like to add an additional logger in my class using lombok + @slf4j.
Currently, I am using @Slf4j which creates

> private static final org.slf4j.Logger log =
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogExample.class).

I am using this for standard logging
I would like to create another logger for specific logging in class.

> private static final Logger testLog =
>   LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogExample.class.getName()+".TestLog")

to output specific logs to separate file. This works manually. How can I configure this using lombok @Slf4j

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Lombok does not have this feature: [issue here](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1183)

Maybe in future we will have this useful feature.

However, if you are using a CDI framework you can inject an extra logger in your code.

J2EE way:

```
@Produces
Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
}
```

Injection:

```
@Inject
private Logger auxLogger;
```

Spring way:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
Logger logger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint){
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMethodParameter().getContainingClass());
}
```

Inject with:

```
@Autowired
private Logger auxLogger;
```